# move_upload_file() is not working

Tags: php

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $location = 'uploads/';
    if (!empty($name)){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'Uploaded successful';
        }
    }else
        echo 'Please select a file.';
}?>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am not getting any error but the move_uploaded_file() is not working. It displayed no result on the browser. I have the folder 'uploads/' inside my directory.

Comment: Is your location correct??

Comment: Directory: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorial\fileupload
Folder for moving uploaded file: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\tutorial\fileupload\uploads

Comment: You don't get anything on your browser because `move_upload_file()` returns false on failure and you have no `else` clause for that

Comment: How do i fix it in order to return true on that?

Comment: @LucasTing, would you try to see if `$location` folder is accessible by php by using `file_exists($location)` and print the results back to you

Comment: try using full path `$location = dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . '/uploads/';`. What OS you are using?

Comment: @ShadyAtef, yes it does exist.

Comment: @bansi I'm using Windows.

Comment: @LucasTing as you u windows, the path separator is `\ ` not `/`..
So try it instead

Comment: @ShadyAtef, `$location = 'uploads\' ';` , like this? If that's so, it is still not working.

Comment: @LucasTing, Check if `$tmp_name` does exist, if it does I have no idea what's happening here.
But you may try to handle the warning that may be thrown by `move_uploaded_file()` by setting a custom handler `set_error_handler()`
then you may get a glimpse of what's actually happening

Comment: @ShadyAtef I would not recommend using `\` for path separator even on windows. `/` works just fine in windows also, and is portable to other OS.

Comment: You should ON error reporting in development mode. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, the maximum file size for the file to be uploaded is 2MB. The file that I tried to upload exceed 0.1MB. Thank all of you.